# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n}^2} = \frac{{\pi}^2}{6}$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$ is equal to:

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n}^2} = \frac{{\pi}^2}{6}$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$ is equal to:

I do not know what to try to find the solution. A hint along with the explanation will be helpful. It might be a trivial problem, but I am facing some problem solving.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By absolute convergence, you may write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n}^2}=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{(2p)}^2}+\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{(2p-1)}^2}=\frac14\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p^2}+\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{(2p-1)}^2}.
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah I will be! Sorry I missed some point.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: May I know how did you think of proceeding in this manner, I searched for absolute convergence in wikipedia, but it was quite complicated for me to understand. If possible please explain about absolute convergence.

Comment: Sure. You can *not*, in general, change the order of terms in an infinite sum. If the infinite sum is absolutely convergent, then you are allowed to do so. Now, $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is absolutely convergent, that's why it is OK to decompose the initial series in two different series.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Could we have taken any other 2 different series. Irrespective of the fact that we need to find the sum of $\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39116/discussion-between-wri-sav-and-olivier-oloa).

Answer (score 6):

Observe that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}$$